# AVL-tree insertion complexity proof

Tags: algorithms, trees, avl-trees

I tried to figure out the proof of insertion operation in AVL-tree is O(log n), but I do not know how.
I also tried to find it somewhere on the Internet, but I could not find any good results. Do you guys have any ideas how do we proof that?

Comment: Take a look at Section 6.2.3 (Balanced Trees) in Volume III (Sorting and Searching) of "The Art of Computer Programming" by Donald Knuth.

Comment: We start by proving that if an AVL tree has a path of length $h$ then the tree has at least $2^{h/2}$ nodes, see this site [AVL tree height log n proof](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/27899/4287).

Comment: At worst, an insertion could cause a rebalancing of every node it traverses, and this is bounded by the tree height. A balanced tree has a height $O(\log n)$.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. For a better *theoretical* understanding of the whole theory I would suggest you to re-read "Introduction to Algorithms, Third Edition, Cormen" Chapter 12 (Trees) and Chapter 13 (Red-Black Trees). Since it is stated there that (page 311):

> As an immediate consequence of this lemma, we can implement the
> dynamic-set operations SEARCH , MINIMUM , MAXIMUM , SUCCESSOR ,
> and PREDECESSOR in $O(\log n)$ time on red-black trees, since each can
> run in $O(h)$ time on a binary search tree of height $h$ (as shown in
> Chapter 12) and any red-black tree on n nodes is a binary search tree
> with height $O(\log n)$.

Red-Black trees do not differ from AVL-trees from a strict computational point of view: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/red-black-tree-vs-avl-tree/. An AVL tree is a subset of a Red-Black tree: http://discuss.fogcreek.com/joelonsoftware/default.asp?cmd=show&ixPost=22948. So from a theoretical point of view, you can map them together (computational-complexity wise).

Regarding a pure understanding of why the INSERTION is $O(\log n)$, check this [implementation example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/avl-tree-set-1-insertion/). There you can clearly see that what makes an AVL differ from a standard BST are the rotations, that can be performed in constant time. With those you get a balanced tree, and with a balanced tree you get $O(\log n)$ INSERTION.

Answer (score 0):

An insertion could at worse cause a rotation on every level, hence with complexity $O(h)$ where $h$ stands for the height.

Now thanks to balancing, $h=O(\log n)$.