# Why is a recurrence of $2N_{h-2}$ equal to $2^{h/2}$?

Tags: recursion, binary-trees, subtree

I was watching video [*7. Binary Trees, Part 2: AVL*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U1JYwHcFfso&list=PLUl4u3cNGP63EdVPNLG3ToM6LaEUuStEY&index=10), where professor Erik Demaine stated that $$2N_{h-2} = 2^{h/2\text{ (or maybe with floor or something... maybe it's ceiling)}}$$ where $N$ stands for the number of nodes in a subtree of height $h-2$. Can someone explain me in more detail why this recursion can be solved like this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Don't understand one step for AVL tree height log n proof](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/27899/dont-understand-one-step-for-avl-tree-height-log-n-proof)

Answer (score 1):

In the lecture it was shown that $N_h \geq 2N_{h-2}$. You can obtain the bound of $2^{h/2} $ for this recurrence by continued expansion of the r.h.s., also called unrolling the recurrence. E.g. :

$N_h \geq 2N_{h-2} = 2 * (2N_{h-4}) = 2*(2*(2N_{h-6})) = 2(2(2(...(2N_0)...)))$.

This expansion will continue until you reach $N_0$, which is 1, I think since the tree with height 0 has only the root. The number of times you can subtract 2 from $h$ is at most $\lceil h/2\rceil$, which is also the number of 2's in the expansion. Thus you have $N_h \geq 2^{\lceil h/2\rceil}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $N_h$ denote the minimum number of nodes in a height-balanced tree of height $h$.  Given a height-balanced tree of height $h$, without loss of generality assume the left child of the root has height $h-1$.  The right child must have height $h-1$ or $h-2$, and to get the smallest possible values (the worst-case), assume it has height $h-2$.  Then, the number of nodes in the given tree is at least $N_{h-1} + N_{h-2} + 1$, because there are at least $N_{h-1}$ nodes in the left subtree of the root, at least $N_{h-2}$ nodes (in the worst case) in the right subtree of the root, and the root itself contributes 1 to the count of number of nodes.

Thus, we get that $N_h \ge N_{h-1} + N_{h-2} + 1$.  One can pay attention to constants and show the terms $N_1, N_2, \ldots$ grow at least as fast as the Fibonacci sequence. The $h$th term of the Fibonacci sequence is at least $c \psi^h$ for some constant $c$ and the golden ratio $\psi$. Hence, the terms of the sequence grow exponentially fast.  This can be shown to imply  that $h$ is at most $1.44 \log n$, and so we get that $h=O(\log n)$ for a height-balanced tree with height $h$ and $n$ nodes.

But, in asymptotic analysis, you can be "sloppy" and ignore constants, and it suffices to use the fact that $N_{h-1}+1 > N_{h-2}$ to get that $N_h \ge N_{h-1}+N_{h-2}+1 > N_{h-2}+N_{h-2}$. Thus, we have $N_h > 2N_{h-2}$. This means the terms of the sequence $N_1, N_2,\ldots$ grow fast enough that they at least double every two terms: $N_3 > 2N_1$, $N_5 > 2N_3 > 4N_1$, and in general, $N_h > N_1 2^{h/2} = N_1 (\sqrt{2})^h$.  This implies that $h < 2 \log n$, and so $h = O(\log n)$.

In general, to show $h=O(\log n)$ for a height-balanced tree, it suffices to show that the number of nodes $n$ grows exponentially with $h$.  The crude analysis given above is good enough to obtain this result.